# Transfrom a forEach function into for loop, with DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom

I am practising with DOM manipulation, in this case with .remove().
I get to find all the 'p' in my HTML and remove them, with a forEach function.

```
     const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p')
    
        ps.forEach(function (p) {
        p.remove()
        })
```

But for the shake of learning, I would like to transform that forEach into a for Loop, but I am not sure how to fill in the function to make it work .
I am trying :

```
    const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p')
    
    for (i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    
    p.remove()
    
    }
```

Comment: It would be `p[i].remove()` in the case of a `for..loop`

Comment: you mean ````ps[i].remove()```` , yeah, it worked :) thanks!

would you care to explain why inside the forEach, it works with p.remove() ? is it because p is the argument passed inside function(p) ?

Comment: `p` is not even defined in your second code. You could use it in your first code because it is a param in your forEach callback. You can do ps[i].

Comment: `ps` is a NodeList - therefore `ps[i]`

Comment: clear now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use

```
ps[i].remove()
```

because `ps` contains an array of all `paragraph`. So you want to delete all elements. If you want to access the elements from the array one by one then you have to use `index` (i.e. on which position they are in an array)

**To simulate deletion after 2 second, I've used `setTimeout` of `2s`**

With `forEach` loop

```js
const allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");

setTimeout(() => {
  allP.forEach(p => p.remove())
}, 2000);
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

With `for..loop`

```js
const allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");

setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < allP.length; ++i) {
    allP[i].remove();
  }
}, 2000);
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Comment: hey, thanks! that goes even a bit further :)

Comment: @notADevYet it does not, it just uses a `setTimeout` (for demo purpose) over your coding typo.

Comment: I was meaning more like the full and detailed explanation you gave me ;)

Comment: @notADevYet Please accept the answer if it is what you want...

Comment: @decpk I just did it. Sorry, i still need to learn better how this forum works.